# UICollectionView from storyboard: is scrolling implemented by default?

Tags: ios6, xcode4.6

With *XCode 4.6* building for *iOS 6.1*, I'm using a `UICollectionView` from a storyboard, and I thought that the class implemented scrolling by default.  I have made a simple test app with a storyboard that has just a *Collection View* and one *Collection View Cell*, and code that implements just `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` and `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:`, calling for enough cells so that scrolling is required to see all the cells.

I thought that with nothing else, I would be able to scroll vertically within the `UICollectionView`.  It shows the visible cells but doesn't scroll.  What am I missing here?

Why wouldn't this component allow me to scroll vertically, what am I unable to see?

The implementation code is about as simple as possible:

```
//
//  TestpViewController.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestpViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

@end

//
//  TestpViewController.m
//

#import "TestpViewController.h"

@interface TestpViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

@end

@implementation TestpViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"testCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: We need to see your implementation code.

Comment: I have now included the code.